# WPF Windows Explorer Like Path Textbox with Textbox combined with Comboboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, textbox

I am searching for something like the textbox in the windows explorer

[image: Like this textbox]

How could this be implemented in wpf like a box where when I click on it I can use text to type in and if it is not focused it shows comboboxes like.

Comment: You could do it create 2 objects on yourself. When you click this box change visable="Hidden" and focus on textbox underneath when you could edit text.